# Backbone.history and file download

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm creating a Backbone/Marionette app and I'd like to hove a simple link to download a PDF file like localhost/myapp/catalog.pdf. But since I use Backbone.history.start(); the link doesn't work. How should I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used jquery.fileDownload (https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload) for a similar situation.

Hope this helps.